# SQL Many To Many History Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want hold history of changes of Records in "many to many relation Table". Tables are A, B and AB_Map where AB_Map table is the link table between A and B. Considering table B immutable (records inside table B never change so table B doesn't need an history) The scanario is this:

```
Table A
---------
ID_a (PK)
a_field1
a_field2
a_field3

Table AB_Map
-------------
ID_a (PK, FK1)
ID_b (PK, FK2)
quantity

Table B (Records never update)
----------
ID_b (PK)
b_field1
b_field2
```

So i want hold history of Table A and Table AB_Map.

Only way that i thought is this:

Create Table A_History and Table AB_Map_History:

```
Table A_History
-----------------
ID_a_history (PK)
ID_a (FK)
a_field1
a_field2
a_field3

Table AB_Map_History
--------------------
ID_a_history(PK, FK1)
ID_b (PK, FK2)
quantity
```

For each changes in table A the previous record it will insert in A_History, and linked records in Table AB_Map will insert in AB_Map_History.
This way will create record in Table_Map_History also if there isn't any change between the relation with A to B.
I think that is the easier way to do this, but i don't like to consume memory if doesn't necessary.

So I would like to know if there are other ways to handle this situation and what do you do in these situations.

Now i use this trigger on A table to resolve my situation:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `SaveHistory` BEFORE UPDATE
ON `A` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO A_History(
        ID_a_history,
        ID_a,
        a_field1,
        a_field2,
        a_field3
    )
VALUES(
    null,
    OLD.ID_a,
    OLD.a_field1,
    OLD.a_field2,
    OLD.a_field3
);

INSERT INTO AB_Map_History(
    AB_Map_History.ID_a_history,
    AB_Map_History.ID_b,
    AB_Map_History.qnt_kt
)
SELECT
    LAST_INSERT_ID(), AB_Map.ID_b, AB_Map.qnt_kt
FROM
    AB_Map
WHERE
    AB_Map.ID_a = OLD.ID_a;
END
```

My goal is save records in AB_Map_History only when relation between record in A and records in B change, or when quantity change.

I hope I was clear in explaining my problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I suppose you want to write trigger. It want to fire when change record in A and records in B change, or when quantity change.

Comment: My question is if my approach is correct or there is another alternative that saves space in my database.

Comment: @sanduniYW i've edit the post adding trigger that use now

Comment: Do your code is working fine or not?

Comment: @sanduniYW my code works fine, but i didn't sure of correctness of it in terms of memory